Indesign Index Question
I'm working on a law textbook and I have a list of words my client has given me. I have to feed it into Indesign's (mediocre) indexing function. The problem is, I have to make an index with these words, but instead of page numbers, or in addition to them, I need to somehow reference to sections (as in legal code) and paragraph-numbers which I have placed outside the text-paragraph with a text-anchor to the specific section.
Is there a way to use a specific format, numbers, cross-references as substitute for page numbers? I've been searching the web for days now, and can't find a solution.
Is there any way to do this semi-automatically, or do I have to do create these sections manually? If so, using cross-references, I'd have to adjust section and paragraph-number every time I update the index … that would be suboptimal.
I've already tried the script IndexMatic3 and some other scripts, but they all just support page numbers instead of these custom variables.

EDIT:
I've looked into Framemaker, and it seems to be quite the tool for indexing, but sadly Framemaker is not an option for now, as it's too expensive. We do have a veeeery old version of it lying around on some hard Drive, but we it's not compatible with our OS versions or InDesign.
